# How do I scale each element of a numpy array relative to itself?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to apply `MinMaxScaler` to each element of a numpy array, and I want it vectorized (I don't want to use a for loop).

```
example = np.array([[2.52163839, 2.54165282, 2.12608389, 2.54515915],
                    [2.29481214, 1.78448378, 2.26652405, 2.27311454],
                    [2.31706137, 2.29058921, 1.83225955, 2.29767736]])
```

I want the first element (`[2.52163839, 2.54165282, 2.12608389, 2.54515915]`) scaled relative to itself (so index 2 becomes 0, index 3 becomes 1, etc.),

then the second element (`[2.29481214, 1.78448378, 2.26652405, 2.27311454]`) scaled relative to itself (so index 1 becomes 0, index 0 becomes 1, etc.), and so on for the whole array.

I tried `example = np.array(list(map(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(), example)))`, but it doesn't work because MinMaxScaler requires the thing being scaled to be passed as an argument into the `fit_transform` method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use map with a lambda function. Some reshaping will be needed due to the specifications  of MinmaxScaler

```
np.array(list( map ( lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(\
  x.reshape(-1, 1)) , example) )).reshape(3,4)
```

**Output :**

```
array([[0.94387462, 0.99163317, 0.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 0.        , 0.94456885, 0.95748306],
       [1.        , 0.94539591, 0.        , 0.96001663]])
```

==**Edit:** Addition  to include @NaiveBae's own solution==

Simply scale a Transposed array:

```
MinMaxScaler().fit_transform( example.T ).T
```

This will work because `MinMaxScaler` uses the following as its implementation:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

By transposing , we convert our required axis to axis 0 (first axis).

Comment: Thank you! I also just now figured another way. Transpose the array, apply the scaler, then re-transpose.   
`scaler = MinMaxScaler() `
`example = scaler.fit_transform(example.T)`
`example = example.T`

Comment: You are right. The MinMaxScaler actually uses `axis=0` for finding min, max . So running it  on a transpose will do the trick. And it will probably be faster too. Maybe I should add this to my answer.